# Functions with same Signature in derived class but inherited as Protected

Tags: c++, inheritance

Base class function and derived class function having the same signature but inherited as protected .In main i have assigned derived class object to a base class pointer and i am trying to access the function .It causes error. Is it because of Protected?

```
 class base{

    public:
    void test(){
    cout<<"test in base\n";

    }
    };
    class derived:protected base{

    public:

     void test(){
    cout<<"test in derived\n";

    }

    };



    int main(){

    base *ptr;
    derived obj;
    ptr=&obj;
    ptr->test();

    return 0;
    }
```

error:

```
In function 'int main()':

error: 'base' is an inaccessible base of 'derived'

     ptr=&obj;

          ^~~
```

Comment: Maybe, but you've not posted any code so can't say for sure.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `;` on line 42. Please include the error and the code in the question.

Comment: Have you tried making test() in the base class virtual?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the protected in derived class access specifier

Comment: thats how protected inheritance works, why did you choose to use protected inheritance?

Comment: Did you notice which line gives you the error? The line that calls the `test` function is not necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: you can remove the function call and still get the same error. Please pay attention to the line numbers included in the error message

Comment: the line ptr=&obj causes error. why does it cause ?

Comment: "the line ptr=&obj causes error. why does it cause ?"  Because ptr is a `base*` and obj is-a `derived` which is-not-a `base` (because `protected` inheritance means that obj is-not-a base).

Comment: Why does it is not working with protected inheritance?

Comment: That's how protected inheritance works.  You are telling the compiler that doing `ptr = &obj` is not allowed, so the compiler prints out an error.

Comment: @SelvaBharathi Now that you see which line causes the error, do you see how the focus of your question is misplaced? You spent so much space discussing the function, yet that is irrelevant. You could remove that function from your example code and still have the error. A well-focused question can save everyone time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
The code in the question changed so I change the whole answer:

[both Private and protected](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance) inheritance allow overriding virtual functions in the private/protected base class, **neither claims the derived is a kind-of its base.** So ptr=&obj; doesn't work because they are not the same type.

> protected inheritance allows derived classes of derived classes to
>   know about the inheritance relationship. Thus your grand kids are
>   effectively exposed to your implementation details. This has both
>   benefits (it allows derived classes of the protected derived class to
>   exploit the relationship to the protected base class) and costs (the
>   protected derived class can’t change the relationship without
>   potentially breaking further derived classes).

Comment: nope. The error is not due to calling the function but due to `ptr=&obj;`. Doesnt work with protected inheritance

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 seems the question changes a lot :)

Comment: "You have public inheritance not protected." op first posted the wrong code

Comment: why does it is not working with protected inheritance? due to compile time binding it must bind with type of pointer so base function must be called.

Comment: @SelvaBharathi read about the purpose of protected inheritance in the link I cited.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using protected inheritance to the outside world `derived` is not derived from `base`, only `derived` and its subclasses know that it is derived from `base`.

Therefore:

```
base *ptr;
derived obj;
ptr=&obj;
```

Is assigning `derived*` to the completely unrelated type `base*`. If you want `derived` to be convertible to `base` you need to use `public` inheritance, `protected` inheritance deliberately hides your base class from the outside world.